# Having problems with reading data from the serial port

Tags: python, pyserial

Having issues reading data from a serial connection. I connect and send write instructions to the device connected to the serial port but when I get a response back it is not in the form it should be taking. What I expect should look something like `"^S015NOM120,60,,,600"` but it looks like `"8"`. I need to be able to read the correct message, and if you know how to continuously read look for messages I would be much appreciated.

I have tried `serial.readlines()`, `serail.readline()`, `io.readlines()`, and `io.readline()`. These keep giving me back error to their arguments.

```
def testcommand():
    ser = serial.Serial('COM7',9600)
    command = b'^P003NOM'
    ser.write(command)
    testread =ser.read(55)
    print(testread)
```

Comment: Can you say what device you're connecting to? and maybe what hardware are you using on your computer side (USB to RS232 adaptor or native RS232 port). Have you checked your baudrates and stop bits are the same?

Comment: It looks like ser.read(55) should read 55 bytes. Can you update the question with the hex of these 55 bytes?

Comment: I had the communication protocols from the manufacture of the device. I was able to write to the device getting it to turn on and off with commands thru the serial port. Turns out I missed the argument in serial.Serial timeout and that is why it was not reading.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. In the serial.serial python will not read unless it know how long it should listen for. It now provides me with an answer I was expecting. I also switched read to readline().

```
serial.Serial('COM7',9600, timeout = 1)
testread = readline()
```